# How to read a csv file and assign values to the variable in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to achieve the below.
I have csv file with the below content

```
Sno,ColumnName,ColumnValue
——————————-———————————
1,svEmp,(Case when col1 = 1 then 2 else 1 end)
2,svCol,(Case when col2 = 2 then 3 else 6 end)
```

I have a requirement where I need to read the csv file in spark scala and assign the `columnValue` to `ColumnName`(create staging variables which can be later used in spark.sql statements) as below

```
val svEmp = "(Case when col1 = 1 then 2 else 1 end)"
//and so on

spark.sql("select $svEmp as CalCol from tableName")
```

How is this achievable?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you share your code  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the CSV that contains select expression into dataframe then aggregate to concatenate the columns `ColumnValue` and `ColumnName`, and finally collect the generated select statement into string variable :

```scala
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(path)

val selectStm = df.agg(
    concat_ws(
      ", ",
      collect_list(concat(col("ColumnValue"), lit(" as "), col("ColumnName")))
    )
  ).first.getString(0)

//selectStm: String = (Case when col1 = 1 then 2 else 1 end) as svEmp, (Case when col2 = 2 then 3 else 6 end) as svCol

val sqlQuery = s"select $selectStm from tableName"
//sqlQuery: String = select (Case when col1 = 1 then 2 else 1 end) as svEmp, (Case when col2 = 2 then 3 else 6 end) as svCol from tableName

val df2 = spark.sql(sqlQuery)
```

Comment: Thanks blackbishop!! The solution below helps when we are selecting the variables without performing any transformation on them. What if we have a statement as spark.sql("select $svEmp+4 as col1, col3, $svCol+$svEmp as CalCol from tableName")